# C++ pointer array seems not to be logical

Tags: c++, pointers

A basic C++ string/pointer question. The question is contained in the comments at the end - namely why doesn't a[0] in the last line produce 'john'?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void funk(char* a[]);

int main() {

    char* z[5];
    z[0] = "john";
    z[1] = "susan";
    z[2] = "holly";
    z[3] = "simon";
    z[4] = "lucinda";

    funk(z);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void funk(char* a[]) {

    cout << a[0] << endl; // prints 'john'.
    cout << *a << endl; // prints 'john'.
    a++;
    cout << *a << endl; // prints 'susan'.
    a++;
    cout << *a << endl; // prints 'holly'.
    cout << a[0] << endl; // prints 'holly' again. But why?! Why doesn't it print 'john'?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two

```
a++;
```

`a` points to two elements forward. Now the new `a[0]` is actually the same as the previous `a[2]`, thus printing `holly`.

Answer (score 1):

Both outputting the same ("holly") was expected.

`a[i]` is a shorthand for `*(a + i)` so your last line really is `*(a + 0)`, or `*a`, which was the previously executed code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't print `"john"` because arrays when passed to functions decays to pointers, and when you modify `a` (i.e. when you do `a++`) you loose the original pointer.

Also note that `a[x]` is always equivalent to `*(a + x)` (or `*a` if `x` is zero). This means that `a[0]` and `*a` will always give you the same result.